# MySQL sometimes erroneously returns 0 for count(*)

Tags: mysql, count

I maintain a forum which paginates forum threads. To determine how many pages a thread has, I perform the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
    FROM `forum_posts`
    WHERE `thread_id` = '3004'
    AND `deleted` = 0;
```

Then get the result, divide it by the number of posts per page, and round up. The above queries occasionally return a result of 0 for no reason that I can fathom, which results in broken pagination. Usually the problem "magically" fixes itself within a few minutes so it's been an interesting journey even diagnosing it this far. Or rather, it can go on for hours but seems to magically fix itself a few moments after I log in to try to see what's going on (although this may be my imagination).

When the problem manifests *all* such queries return 0 for `numrows`, and when it resolves itself suddenly the above queries start returning the correct values again.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: What would cause this issue is that no rows satisfy the `where` conditions.

Comment: Indeed, that would make sense, but is not the case :( Every thread has at least one post by definition, and this occurs intermittently to all threads regardless of the number of posts.

Comment: Or the query fails (and you don't handle the errors correctly).

Comment: Get the server to keep a log of the queries that are made. Wait for the error to occur, and look at the log to see if the query has changed.

Comment: @Simba the query above is pulled directly from such a log I started up trying to diagnose this.

Comment: @Pred interesting... I'd be surprised not to get warnings / errors thrown at me, but I shall try to see if this is the issue.

Comment: Are there other clients modifying the table at the same time? Are you using transactions?

Comment: It that mySQL's own log file or a log created by your application?

Comment: I did not say, you don't get any errors/warnings. You do and it is possible, that your db access layer catches them silently -> the result of your query will lead to FALSE or NULL -> NULL/FALSE will be casted to 0 during the calculation of the pages -> 0/anything (except 0) is 0.

Comment: @Pred oh goodness I just checked the source code of the db access layer and you're right -- if the result of count(*) returns no rows it silently returns 0. Nghh. I just pushed a modification to log the results of `show warnings` next time that condition fires, and see what it has to say.

Comment: PSA if you're making a db access layer please do not silently mask errors or warnings :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer contains lots of guessing, the original question did not contain enough info to be sure about these. However, this answer might be useful for further readers.

> The above queries occasionally return a result of 0 for no reason that I can fathom, which results in broken pagination.

You can get 0 records (or 0 in a COUNT(*) query) when

1. No rows are satisfying the WHERE conditions (e.g. no posts in a forum thread).
2. There is an error/exception somewhere between the 'seems to be bad' query and the code point where you found the error. (For example the client can not connect to the database server and the error is silently ignored).

> When the problem manifests all such queries return 0 for numrows, and when it resolves itself suddenly the above queries start returning the correct values again.

In this particular case, my bet is: the max connection count in mysql is reached.
The database access layer silently ignores the error, which leads to a result which can be casted to the numeric value 0. As we know, dividing 0 by anything (except 0) equals to 0.

Here is an example (copy-pasters: do not use this code!)

```
try {
    /**
      Note for OO syntax only: If a connection fails an object is still returned.
      To check if the connection failed then use either the
      mysqli_connect_error() function or the
      mysqli->connect_error property as in the preceding examples.
    */
    $connection = new \mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'superSecretPass', 'database');
    $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM myTable WHERE this_flag IS NULL';
    $result = $connection->query($connection, $query);
    $itemCount = $result->fetchAssoc()['cnt'];
    $result->close();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    //Do nothing
}

$itemsPerPage = 15;
$sumPages = \ceil($itemCount / $itemsPerPage);
```

When an exception occurs or a connection error is not handled in the above example:

- $itemCount is not defined
- $itemCount will be treated as NULL
- NULL will be casted to 0
- 0/15 = 0

If you want to handle errors in a bottom layer (such as database access) class, do it in a way which allows the caller to be notified about an error/exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took your suggestion to verify if it was a failing query, but it seems that everything is khosher: it is *only* this query that returns erroneous results (none of the other myriad of queries involved in rendering that page fail), and no warnings are produced in the DB either.

Comment: I am at quite a loss here... the problem seems to manifest across different sessions, but seems to vanish as soon as I log into mysql from a ssh session. That is, someone notices a thread has zero pages, I look and the thread has zero pages, I ssh to the server, the thread still has zero pages, I log in to mysql (and don't run any queries) and suddenly the threads have pages again.

Comment: This may be wholly irrelevant, but I first started noticing this issue shortly after I migrated the tables from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Comment: As a first step, you can start here (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html).Your 3 comments long text indicates, that this is another question.Not a good idea to talk about something like this in the comments.As a rule of thumb, when you can't present your addition in one comment, it is a new question, or your original question did not provide all the information what is needed to solve the problem.My suggestion is to open a new question, include ALL the steps required to reproduce the problem.The original one is a design problem, the new one is a software related one.

Answer (score 5):

We faced this problem as well. It also occurred from the mysql client (not through code). It seems to be a bug with mysql. It's caused by index merge intersection

You can either set it off per session and try
SET SESSION optimizer_switch="index_merge_intersection=off";

Or set it globally in your my.cnf

[mysqld]
optimizer_switch=index_merge_intersection=off

Bug report filed here

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81031

Comment: First place I was able to find a reference to this bug report that was effecting us too. Thanks