# MySQL is not correctly selecting rows (sometimes)

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

This is an update to this question, wherein I was casting around trying to work out what on earth was going on:

[MySQL sometimes erroneously returns 0 for count(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973835/mysql-sometimes-erroneously-returns-0-for-count)

I ended up accepting an answer there because it did answer the question I posed ("why might this happen") even though it didn't answer the question I really wanted to know about ("why is this happening to me"). **But** I've managed to narrow things down a little bit on the latter question, and think I can definitively say that something is wrong in a way that I don't understand and have never seen before.

The issue has been really difficult to debug because, for reasons beyond my comprehension, logging in to the database automagically fixes it. However, today I managed to trigger the problematic state while having an open MySQL session in a terminal. Here are some queries and the subsequent responses taken from that session:

First, this is my table layout:

```
mysql> describe forum_posts;                                                    
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| post_id   | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| thread_id | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| forum_id  | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id   | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| moderator | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| message   | mediumtext | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date      | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| edited    | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted   | tinyint(1) | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| bbcode    | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, lets look at how many posts there are in a given forum thread:

```
mysql> SELECT count(post_id) as num FROM `forum_posts` where thread_id=5243;
+-----+
| num |
+-----+
| 195 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

OK, but I only want forum posts that don't have the `deleted` flag set:

```
mysql> SELECT count(post_id) as num FROM `forum_posts` where thread_id=5243 and deleted=0;
+-----+
| num |
+-----+
|   0 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> select post_id,deleted from forum_posts where thread_id=5243 and deleted=0;
Empty set (0.06 sec)
```

OK, lets just double-make-sure that they aren't actually all deleted:

```
mysql> select post_id,deleted from forum_posts where thread_id=5243;
+---------+---------+
| post_id | deleted |
+---------+---------+
|  104081 |       0 |
|  104082 |       0 |

[snip]

|  121162 |       0 |
|  121594 |       0 |
+---------+---------+
195 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Every row in that table has 'deleted' set to 0, and yet adding `and deleted=0` to the query yields no results. Until I open a new session by logging in to MySQL again from a terminal window, after which I can once again properly select rows where 'deleted' is 0.

What on earth?

---

**UPDATES:**

@miken32 in the comments below suggested I try an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, so:

```
mysql> explain select post_id,deleted from forum_posts where thread_id='5243' and deleted=0;
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type        | possible_keys     | key               | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | forum_posts | index_merge | thread_id,deleted | thread_id,deleted | 5,2     | NULL |   97 | Using intersect(thread_id,deleted); Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Has your server recently been possessed by demons, ghosts or other otherworldly creatures?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. And it doesn't seem to be platform specific either. I have reproduced this error both on my production server running Debian Wheezy, and my local laptop with a copy of the code and database (as copied over via mysqldump) running Debian sid.

Comment: Try your dump with http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: if it was me i would export the table, then drop it and the db and recreate

Comment: Really strange. You can try: deleted = '0'

Comment: @Dagon I've essentially tried this. The problem does indeed temporarily go away just as it does any time I log in to the database, but a few days later it comes back again.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis: it has the same effect

Comment: Does `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` show anything odd when it's doing this?

Comment: Quick question, due to how null fields can cause weird WHERE results; why is your deleted a null-able field when it really should only ever be 0 or 1?

Comment: This question might be better suited for [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). See their "Is my question on-topic" for more details. This problem seems isolated to the database, and I do not see an obvious reason why this would happen, unless you rebuild your entire database causing it to be momentarily empty when you do this query... Their knowledge of the underlying architecture is likely much greater.

Comment: @miken32 I've edited it into the question since comment format would mangle it. It looks... fine to me? I'm not really sure, I haven't used `explain` much before

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: It might be that your index is corrupted. Try to drop your index on deleted and re-create it. The explain shows that it is using an index scan. Also, try `select count(*)` instead of `select count(post_id)`. MySQL sometimes has some 'features' that other databases don't.

Comment: Kind of odd that `EXPLAIN` only shows 97 rows, but otherwise looks normal.

Comment: (And also, what storage engine are you using, and have you run a `CHECK TABLE`?)

Comment: What happens if you do ```select post_id,deleted from forum_posts force key(thread_id) where thread_id='5243' and deleted=0``` and ```select post_id,deleted from forum_posts force key(thread_id) where thread_id='5243' and deleted=0``` ?

Comment: And what is the version of MySQL on both systems where the problem reproduced?

Comment: @Chloe: I had the same idea and have done that already -- iirc the problem clears up, but comes back before too long. If it's a corrupted index, then something is corrupting it somehow...

Comment: @MattGibson: I'm using InnoDB for all tables. `check table forum_posts` returns `OK`

Comment: Make deleted NOT NULL and try: SELECT COUNT(ALL 1). I know it's not the solution but you can try it to see if something changes.

Comment: @SashaPachev: I think we're getting somewhere! Those queries return the correct results. Those queries ignore the key on `deleted`, right? Which would imply that somehow that key is doing something bad?

Comment: Are you using version 5.1 of MySQL?

Comment: @MattGibson: one's using 5.6.25-4 on Debian sid, the other's using 5.6.27 on Debian wheezy

Comment: @MiDri: you're right, there's no reason this should be null so I've updated it to be a non-nullable field (thanks for catching that!). Unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: This question might be stupid, but let's see: 0 is the default value; are your zero values expressly set to zero or are they not set, resulting to default value? Does it make a difference if you manually update all default zero values to zero? (Doing it in two steps, first update to unused value 2, then update to 0 again, so you can check that the where clause of your update doesn't trick you in any way...)

Comment: Have you tried putting brackets in: where (thread_id=5243) and (deleted=0); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment that using FORCE KEY alters the result from the query, it is very likely that we are dealing with the merge optimizer bug. EXPLAIN of the original query shows the optimization is done by selecting from the deleted key, then from the post_id key, then merging the results. When we force to bypass that code, the problem goes away.

The steps from the point:

- try it on the same data with the most recent 5.6 version of MySQL
- if the issue reproduces, try to isolate it to the most minimal test case, visit http://bugs.mysql.com/ and report the bug

Comment: As far as my application goes, is it a reasonable fix just to use `force key`  in production? Or is this just "masking" what may be a potentially much worse issue that I simply haven't yet discovered?

Comment: If this is indeed a merge optimizer bug, it could potentially affect other queries that hit the same code path. So I would work on getting it resolved just for that reason. Plus it is a service to the MySQL community, helps make MySQL better.

Answer (score 0):

Exorcise the daemons and ghosts!  Add this index to avoid any "merge" bug:

```
INDEX(deleted, thread_id)  and DROP the key on just deleted
```

An index on a flag is almost always useless.  This time it was worse than useless.

This wil be cheaper, faster, and safer than FORCE INDEX.